# Error in cor(Auto[, -9]) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r

```
data("Auto")
mpg01 <- rep(0, length(Auto$mpg))
mpg01[Auto$mpg > median(Auto$mpg)] <- 1
Auto <- data.frame(Auto, mpg01)
summary(Auto)
cor(Auto[, -9])
Error in cor(Auto[, -9]) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I don't know how deal with this error

Comment: We don't have access to the Auto dataset, so we cannot reproduce. My guess is that one of the variables in the dataset is character in nature.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using `ISLR` package - is that correct? It sounds like you may have a column in `Auto` that is character or factor (something non-numeric). Try `str(Auto)` and see what class your columns are.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not referencing the columns correctly. Try -

```
data <- ISLR::Auto
data$mpg01 <- as.integer(data$mpg > median(data$mpg))
cor(data[, -9])

#               mpg cylinders displacement horsepower weight acceleration  year origin mpg01
#mpg           1.00     -0.78        -0.81      -0.78  -0.83         0.42  0.58   0.57  0.84
#cylinders    -0.78      1.00         0.95       0.84   0.90        -0.50 -0.35  -0.57 -0.76
#displacement -0.81      0.95         1.00       0.90   0.93        -0.54 -0.37  -0.61 -0.75
#horsepower   -0.78      0.84         0.90       1.00   0.86        -0.69 -0.42  -0.46 -0.67
#weight       -0.83      0.90         0.93       0.86   1.00        -0.42 -0.31  -0.59 -0.76
#acceleration  0.42     -0.50        -0.54      -0.69  -0.42         1.00  0.29   0.21  0.35
#year          0.58     -0.35        -0.37      -0.42  -0.31         0.29  1.00   0.18  0.43
#origin        0.57     -0.57        -0.61      -0.46  -0.59         0.21  0.18   1.00  0.51
#mpg01         0.84     -0.76        -0.75      -0.67  -0.76         0.35  0.43   0.51  1.00
```